# How to copy war file from Jenkins server to Tomcat Server running on GCP cloud

Tags: tomcat, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I am running 2 Ubuntu VMs in the GCP cloud. On the 1st VM I'm running JENKINS Server and on the 2nd I'm running Tomcat Server. I've created a war file on Jenkins Server for a Java project using pipeline script and now I want to deploy the same on the Tomcat server running on a separate VM.

Comment: You can make use of `Copy Artifact Plugin`. Here is an example https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.codurance.com/publications/2014/10/03/guide-to-deploying-artifacts-with-jenkins%3fhs_amp=true

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of ways to do that:

- Using [plugin](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.codurance.com/publications/2014/10/03/guide-to-deploying-artifacts-with-jenkins%3fhs_amp=true) mentioned by @Sourav in the comment.
- You can also use [gcloud scp command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to download the file to you machine and then deploy it using this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war).
- There's another tutorial on [Deploying war file from Jenkins to Tomcat](https://www.jdev.it/deploying-your-war-file-from-jenkins-to-tomcat/).